# How do I install pygame in a pyenv virtualenv for Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, python, virtualenv

I found instructions for Python 3.3 but nothing specifically for 2.7. I sorted it out and figured I'd record it here for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you have [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) installed for your project (`~/my-project-dir`) and your virtualenv (`my-pyenv-virtualenv`) is set up.

To get latest Pygame source, see: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
cd /usr/include/linux/
sudo ln -s ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h
cd ~/my-project-dir
~/.pyenv/versions/my-pyenv-virtualenv/bin/pip install http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz
```

To test

```
~/.pyenv/versions/my-pyenv-virtualenv/bin/python -c "import pygame; print(pygame.vernum)"
```